# Is it possible to travel to multiple Schengen states with a single Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, multiple-entry

I have a valid multiple-entry Schengen visa issued by the Spanish Consulate in Mumbai, India. I will be travelling to Spain on the 26th of March and then to the UK on 31st of March. Would I be able to travel to France when I leave the UK?

Comment: Please note that UK isn't part of Schengen area.

Answer (score 0):

> A Schengen visa obtained by any of the Schengen Area member countries allows free movement to its holder within the whole Schengen Zone regarding the European Union Schengen members as well as the EFTA Schengen members, up to its validity and timeframe.

So the countries you can travel using a schengen visa are

> Austria, Belgium, the Czech Republic, Denmark,
> Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia,
> Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, the Netherlands, Norway, Poland,
> Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden and Switzerland. **Plus** Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus and Romania

The visa policy can be found here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area

These countries apply the
common visa policy for short stay visas

#### From these, Let me conclude that you can travel to Spain, France without restiction since all of them are schengen members but UK is not a schengen member.

More details can be found here : [eeas.europa [pdf]](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf)

Comment: UK isn't part of Schengen...

Comment: yes you are correct. Thanks for pointing @Laurent

Comment: Please do not cite schengenvisainfo.com for truth -- it is a private website that exists solely to accumulate ad impressions, and its information is _not_ kept accurate or up to date. (It kept claiming that there were such a thing as type-B visas for well over 5 years after they were abolished, for example).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I removed the cite. But the quote is there because wikipedia also tells the same. Is there any problem with this. Do I have to update the quote too?

Comment: @SagarV: That particular quote does not seem to be wrong, though the "regarding the European Union Schengen members as well as the EFTA Schengen members" part seems to be more confusing than informative.

Comment: I will clarify it now.

Comment: Are you associated with  schengenvisainfo.com?

Comment: @GayotFow today itsel I heard of the site for the first time. I already removed it from answer by some comments and some security testing on the site. It is a malicious site. The site link is there in only rev. History

Comment: @SagarV thanks, if you stick to the eu domains you'll be fine. I was wondering why you answered a question already addressed by one of the canonical's, hence my question.  There's a Schengen 'go to' thread in META you might consider adding to.